# How to mock a real running applicaton?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, microservices

One of my Microservice [`MS1`] checks another Microservice [`MS2`] at startup, if MS2 is running or not. If MS2 is running MS1 will start else fails to start.

But currently I am running `MS2` on my local machine which takes a huge amount of `RAM` ans slow down my machine.

Is there any mechanism so that when MS1 starts and look-up for MS2 it seems that MS2 is running without actually running real MS2?

---

Update :

Let's assume MS2 is running on `localhost:1234` and now MS1 will connect to it using REST.

Comment: You have to add code code how MS1 is checking for presence of MS2

Comment: I wanted to know if you are using REST, grpc or  socket to check presence.

Comment: Connecting it using REST

Comment: Have you looked at the library that I linked in my answer? This is perfect solution for you...

Comment: @michalk I am working on the same. I think it will work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a look at [`WireMock`](http://wiremock.org/) which is a simulator of HTTP API so it will be suitable for local development. When using it you will be able to mimic a microservice as if it was running as a standalone microservice on given host and port.

You can run it both as a standalone process and as a part of your spring application.

**Option 1 - configuring standalone wiremock server :**

1. Download [Wiremock Standalone jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone)
2. Run standalone server on localhost with port `1234` :

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar --port 1234
```

3. Configure your MS1 microservice to use `localhost:1234` as your MS2 host.
4. Mock your MS2(mocked with wiremock) endpoint with some response :

```
curl -X POST --data '{ "request": { "url": "/yourendpoint", "method": "GET" }, "response": { "status": 200, "body": "Response" }}' http://localhost:1234/__admin/mappings/new
```

Here we make a mock that when you hit on your mocked server on `/yourendpoint` with HTTP GET you will receive text `Response` as response.

5. Now when you hit with GET on `localhost:1234/yourendpoint` you get your mocked response :

```
curl http://localhost:1234/yourendpoint
Response
```

Full example can be found at [`Wiremock Standalone docs`](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/)

---

**Option 2 - configuring WireMock server in your Spring app :**

1. Add [`WireMock dependency`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock) to your project (watch out to add it not only to test scope)
2. Create a Spring bean used to set up your server :

```
@Component
public class CustomMicroserviceMock {

    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    public CustomMicroserviceMock() {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(1234));
        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/yourendpoint"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                        .withBody("Response")));
        wireMockServer.start();
    }


    @PreDestroy
    void preDestroy() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }

}
```

3. When we hit `localhost:1234/yourendpoint` we get response : `Response`

This is just a POC how it could look like but it works in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using WireMock as a standalone service in your local machine, or if you 
are familiar with docker you can check the wiremock docker image :

https://hub.docker.com/r/rodolpheche/wiremock/

I'm using it for my development and testing, it's really a strong stubbing solution :)

Best of luck